# Xcode6で "view is clipping its content" となる原因

Tags: xcode

Xcode4 で作成されたプロジェクトを、Xcode6に移行しています。

すると、nibファイルで表題の通り「View is clipping its content」というwarning(?)が出ています。
show the issue navigator に、灰色の円内に白抜きの「!」が表示されています。

> ！Clipped Content
>   　　View is clipping its content

問題の部分をクリックすると、nibファイルが開き、NSTextFieldが選択された状態になります。
画面を見ても、特に対象のNSTextFieldが途中できれてしまっていたりはしません。

実害はないとは思うのですが、どうも気になるので、分かる方がいらっしゃいましたら教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

手元では、新規プロジェクトで `NSTextField` を配置し、長めのプレースホルダテキストを設定するだけで再現しました。

> 特に対象のNSTextFieldが途中できれてしまっていたりはしません。

Interface Builder は可読性のために必要なマージン等も含めて計算していると思うので、必ずしもテキストがすべて見えていれば OK というわけではないと思います。

Editor > Size to Fit Content を実行すると、IB が計算した最小サイズに合わせることができます。

古いプロジェクトを移行されているとのことなので、システムフォントの変化が影響していたりするのかなと想像しています。

Comment: Editor > Size to Fit Content を試してみましたが、残念ながら問題は解決しませんでした。

新たに１つ分かった事としては、nibファイルを開くまでは発生しないようです。
古いプロジェクトを開き、何も操作せずにビルドすると問題は発生しませんでした。
その後、nibファイルをクリックして開いただけで問題が発生します。

Answer (score 0):

当該オブジェクトのConstrainsを一旦、解除して、再度設定し直してみるとどうでしょうか？